# How to check if address is contained in a continent or close to another address in android google maps api v2?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

In my app, I have a list of locations, and I want to create filter settings. I am looking for a way so that a user can pick maybe a continent or country or address and then filter out the locations from the list if the location is within the continent or country or close to the address.

Is there a google maps v2 api for android that can do something like:

```
public Boolean AddressIsContained(String address, String place);
```

which returns true if `address` is within `place` (`place` could be like a country or continent). And also like

```
public Boolean AddressCloseTo(String address1, String address2, int distance);
```

which returns true if `address1`is within `distance` amount of kilometers to `address2`. And this would just be a straight line between the addresses, nothing like a bike, walk, car or plane route.

Also for the list of locations, I am also able to access its lat/long if that makes it easier.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For the start I assume you are familiar with the [GeoCoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html) and / or [GeoCoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/?hl=en) to get the addresses for your locations.

If you use the GeoCoder you will get a List of Address objects. The [Address](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Address.html) class provides some methodes to get the country or city name f.e. These methods you can use for your filter.

The [Location](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html) class includes the methods distanceBetween() and distanceTo(). These you can use to check the distance between your locations.